# Oracle hibernate ID generator using sequence and global sequence

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc

```
package com.abc.entity;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

    @Entity (name = "Employee")
    @Table(name="EMPLOYEE")
    public class EmployeeEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, 
    generator="oracle_seq")
    @SequenceGenerator(name="oracle_seq", 
    sequenceName="MY_ENTITY_SEQ")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name="FIRSTNAME")
    private String firstname;

    @Column(name="LASTNAME")
    private String lastname;

    @Column(name="EMAIL")
    private String email;

    @Column(name="TELEPHONE")
    private String telephone;


    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }
    public String getTelephone() {
        return telephone;
    }
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
    public void setTelephone(String telephone) {
        this.telephone = telephone;
    }
    public String getFirstname() {
        return firstname;
    }
    public String getLastname() {
        return lastname;
    }
    public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
    }
    public void setLastname(String lastname) {
        this.lastname = lastname;
    }
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

**Important Note** : @GeneratedValue(strategy =GenerationType.AUTO) will use single global sequence hibernate_sequence if we do no specify our own sequence

But getting cannot insert null into ("DB","EMPLOYEE","ID")
Another way of creating sequence

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="oracle_seq")
@SequenceGenerator(name="oracle_seq", sequenceName="MY_ENTITY_SEQ")
```

but this is also giving
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'editEmployeeController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed;**{{some nested exception}}**  **Unknown Id.generator: ORACLE_SEQ**

Here is the **image from DB browser**:

[Here I have created sequence in db click here see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VZn5X.jpg)

**Hibernate Configuration file**

```
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <mapping class="com.howtodoinjava.entity.EmployeeEntity" />
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Comment: @sbjavateam I have the sequence seriously I have tried like 50 times still not working don't a single piece of idea why it is not working while everywhere in docs or oracle sequence generator reference I have seen the same exact thing .......THOUGH I DIDN'T do this NOCACHE NOCYLE I guess this will not effect

Comment: @sbjavateam I have added image of my db browser where I am showing you sequence created in DB please see at last given the link
Also see the changed entity also added hibernate configuration code this file is in my resource folder remember